# Convergence of partial sums to Fourier series?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, fourier-series, lp-spaces

I am relatively new to Fourier series. Let  $f \in L^2([-\pi, \pi])$ with $f(-\pi) = f(\pi)$. The Fourier coefficients of $f$ are given by
\begin{align*}
\hat{f}(n) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) e^{-int} \, dt,
\end{align*}
the partial sums of the Fourier series of $f$ are given by
\begin{align*}
s_N(t) = \sum \limits_{-N}^N \hat{f}(n) e^{int},
\end{align*}
and the Fourier series of $f$ is given by
\begin{align*}
F(t) = \sum_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(n) e^{int}.
\end{align*}

My question is: **do the functions $s_N$ converge pointwise to $F$?**

It seems to me that this should both be true, but then I derive a contradiction. It is known that the $s_N$ converge to $f$ in the $L^2$ norm, and so a subsequence $(s_{N_k})_k$ converges pointwise to $f$. This implies that $f=F$ almost everywhere, but since $s_N \rightarrow F$ pointwise, we get $s_N \rightarrow f$ pointwise almost everywhere.

But as far as I can tell, pointwise convergence of the Fourier series to the original function $f$ is a very difficult question. **Is the "almost everywhere" what makes a difference? Did I make a mistake in my argument? Or do the $s_N$ just not converge pointwise to $F$?**

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Convergence_almost_everywhere

Comment: @metamorphy So, if I understand correctly, $s_N$ converges pointwise everywhere to $F$ and $f=F$ a.e.? So the real question is whether "almost everywhere" can be strengthened to "everywhere"?

Comment: If $f \in L^1$ then it is not necessarily true that that its Fourier series converges a.e. (In fact, it's possible for the series to diverge everywhere.) If $f \in L^1$ and $f \in L^p$ for some $p > 1$ then it is true that the Fourier series converges a.e. to $f$, but it's a very big and difficult theorem (Carleson-Hunt).

Comment: What is not difficult is to show: that $S_N$ converges to $F$ in the $L^2$ norm (completeness and orthogonality of the $e^{int}$ in the Hilbert space), and when $F,F'$ are continuous then $S_N$ converges uniformly to $F$ (Dirichlet kernel).

Comment: (I am an idiot sorry). I am slightly confused. Isn't $F(t)$ the limit as $N$ goes to $\infty$ of $s_N$? Isn't that essentially the definition? Or is it saying that $s_N$ approaches $F(t)$ because if it does, then nothing changes. But if we have $F(t)$ goes to $s_N$, we have something rather trivial. (Once again I apologize for being stupid. I am stupid, but I enjoy maths).

Comment: @toolfan3 - the issue is with the definition $F(t) = \sum \hat{f}(n)e^{int}$. The LHS is not defined at points where the RHS fails to converge pointwise, and if we only have the hypothesis that $f \in L^2$, and no additional hypotheses such as the ones given by **reuns**, then we need the Carleson-Hunt sledgehammer to conclude that the RHS converges pointwise a.e.

Comment: To see how bad it can get, note that the Fourier coefficients $\hat{f}(n)$ are defined (the defining integral exists and is finite) if and only if $f \in L^1$, but there exist $L^1$ functions whose Fourier series do not converge anywhere!

Comment: @reuns - In your comment, I believe you meant $f$ everywhere you wrote $F$, correct? The question is somewhat confusing because $F$ is "defined" as the function to which the series converges (assuming it does) but the OP then asks "do the functions $s_n$ converge to $F$?" when I think he/she really wants to know whether they converge to $f$.

Comment: Well the result is affirmative and it's a rather non-trivial result in Fourier Analysis, and it's the famous Carleson's theorem. In fact the result is true for $L^p[-\pi,\pi]$ as long as $1<p<\infty$

Comment: @Bungo Thanks for pointing out that the RHS doesn't necessarily converge pointwise a.e.; I didn't realize that was the case. So, in this case, does "the fourier series of $f$" just mean $\sum \hat{f}(n) e^{int}$ as a formal sum, and not necessarily a function? (A priori, that is; without appealing to Carleson-Hunt).

Comment: @Sambo - Yes, that's correct, "the Fourier series of $f$" refers to the formal sum, which may or may not converge in various senses, depending on what hypotheses are assumed for $f$.

Comment: Btw, to give you an indication how much is involved in proving Carleson-Hunt, it's essentially the culmination of Grafakos' two-volume set, [Classical Fourier Analysis](https://www.amazon.com/Classical-Fourier-Analysis-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/1493911937) and [Modern Fourier Analysis](https://www.amazon.com/Modern-Fourier-Analysis-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/1493912291). To even start reading these books, you need to already know Fourier analysis at the level of, say, [Katznelson](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Harmonic-Analysis-Cambridge-Mathematical/dp/0521543592).

Comment: @Bungo Good to know!! I'll safely mark that as "not needed" for my upcoming exam then xD